# Вывод подменю на странице WP. В чем разница двух кодов?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код для вывода подменю на странице WP, он работает.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects_filter', 10, 2 );

function wp_nav_menu_objects_filter( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( 'Main' !== $args->menu ) {
      return $sorted_menu_items;
  }

  $items        = array();
  $current_item = null;

  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $item ) {
    if ( $current_item && intval( $item->menu_item_parent ) === $current_item ) {
        $items[] = $item;
        continue;
    }

    if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes, true ) ) {
        $current_item = $item->ID;
        // $items[]      = $item;
        continue;
    }
  }

  return $items;
}
```

Но, если переписать его вот так, то уже нет. В чем разница, почему один работает, а второй нет?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_nav_menu_objects_filter', 10, 2 );

function wp_nav_menu_objects_filter( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( 'Main' !== $args->menu ) {
      return $sorted_menu_items;
  }
  $items = array();
  $current_item = null;

  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items  as $item) {
    if ( in_array( 'current_page_item', $item->classes, true ) ) {
      $current_item = $item->ID;
            continue;
     }
   }

  foreach ( $sorted_menu_items  as $item) {
    if ( $current_item && intval( $item->menu_item_parent ) === $current_item ) {
        $items[] = $item;
        continue;
      }
   }

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Что именно изменилось?

Comment: @Эникейщик, Вместо одного `foreach` в котором находили активный пункт меню и после записывали дочерние елементы в массив, стало 2 `foreach` в первом ищем активный елемент, во втором записываем дочерние в массив

Comment: Оба кода идентичны. Прочитал вашу модификацию моего кода три раза и не нашёл отличий - типичный рефакторинг. После этого я даже скопировал ваш код и проверил его в том самом шаблоне страницы, где находится и первый вариант кода. Ваш код работает. Вы ошиблись где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, проблема оказалась во втором `foreach`, пришлось и к `$current_item` добавить `intval`. Может быть это из за версий PHP, у меня 5.6?

Comment: да ну... $current_item и так int. Я потому поставил `intval($item->menu_item_parent)`, что это строка. Приводил к int.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, помогает добавить к `$current_item` или убрать `$item->menu_item_parent`. Подскажите, почему этот код не срабатывает для категорий?

Comment: А как он должен срабатывать для категорий? У вас меню, в котором категории?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, У меня есть примерно вот такая [структура меню](https://ibb.co/dU3V69).
Не много добавив кода у меня получилось и на дочерних страницах выводить подменю.
А в категориях(родительских или дочерних) оно не выводится.

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KAGGDesign, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вы зачем так делаете? Ничего себе "обновил"! Да вы подменили вопрос. Создайте новый, а здесь я откачу правку.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, может его лучше закрыть или удалить. Проблема то вроде бы решена? Но, мое решение не тянет на ответ.

Comment: А где ваше решение? И какого вопроса? Я вижу только свой код, отрефакторенный. Т.е. без изменения его функционала.